# SAS changing a number when proc print?

Tags: encryption, sas, format

When I run a proc print where segment ID equals 1234 the output shows segment ID 1235.  SAS actually changes the last 4 digits of a 19 digit number. Contents shows the field in a num 8 formatted as a char 20. I just pull the data and print with no additional formatting or processing.

If I run a SQL statement in a different software package where segment ID equals 1234 (the exact same record) the results show 1234 (no change to the last 4).  The other vars pulled with the query exactly match those of SAS except for the segment ID.

My best guess is it's a formatting issue even though the field should be large enough, 20 > 19.

Second guess is some sort of encryption on the field.  Typically if I don't have proper  access a field would be blank. But I am unfamiliar with this new data source.

I'll try adding a specific format to my SAS datapull for that field but would love to hear any other suggestions.

Thank you!

Comment: There is already a good answer. An additional comment: only store as numbers, values that are really numbers, i.e. not codes. Even if they are shorter than the maximum 15 digits, codes stored as numbers cause many problems: for instance, the initial zeros may be significant, and you may have to update a table with alphanumeric codes.

Comment: Thank you all for the responses.  A 19 digit number which should have been stored as a char was stored as a num 8.  It was too large for the format to store accurately. I was mistaken in my original post when I said it was a char 20 (I literally had undiagnosed COVID).  I pulled the data again giving the field a proper format and Bob's my uncle.  Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

PROC PRINT is not the issue.  You cannot store 19 decimal digits exactly as a number in SAS.  SAS stores numbers as 64-bit floating point numbers.  The maximum number of decimal digits that can be represented as consecutive integers is 15.  After that the binary representation will not have enough bits to exactly represent every decimal string.
Check this description about precision from the documentation: https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lrcon/p0ji1unv6thm0dn1gp4t01a1u0g6.htm

You should store such things as character strings.  **I doubt that you need to do any arithmetic with those values.**

If you are getting the data from a remote database use the [DBSASTYPE=](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/acreldb/n0v4ma1zb9lu99n1728j279rjcqi.htm) dataset option to control what type of SAS variable is created.

Answer (score 0):

> Contents shows the field in a num 8 formatted as a char 20. I just pull the data and print with no additional formatting or processing.

That doesn't make sense. A numeric variable shouldn't have a character format.

I think you'll need to re-read the source field as a character from the source.  Not sure where you "just pull the data" from, but you'll need to modify that step to ensure it gets brought over as a character in the first place otherwise you'll have that issue no matter what.

You cannot fix the issue with the data as is, as far as I know.

```
*issue with numeric;
data have;
input segmentID;
format segmentID 32.;
segmentIDChar=put(SegmentID, 32.);
cards;
1234567890123456789
;;;;
run;

proc print data=have;
run;

*no issue with character fields;
data have;
length segmentID $20.;
input segmentID $;
format segmentID $32.;
cards;
1234567890123456789
;;;;
run;

proc print data=have;
run;
```

Results:

```
Numeric Isssue
Obs segmentID           segmentIDChar
1   1234567890123456768 1234567890123456768


Character Issue
Obs segmentID
1   1234567890123456789
```